# Why call "monic" an injective function?

Tags: functions, category-theory

In Golan's book  "The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know", the author calls **monic** a function that assigns different elements to different elements. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: This might be related to it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism

Comment: Uh-oh.  Another outbreak of category theory.

Comment: If you *are* a beginning grad student, it actually is a good idea to start getting used to this categorical language. The word "injective" is fine in most cases, although, as you can find on the wikipedia page @pbn990 linked, there are examples of monomorphisms which are not injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the monics in the category of sets are exactly the injective functions. Therefore one can do that, but I think one should not (at least in that context) as it is only confusing.

There is something called category theory where one can define some more general notion of injective maps which are called monics/monomorphisms. Depending on the category, they might not be injective though (and it does not even always make sense to ask whether they are injective because they do not have to be maps and the objects do not necessarily have elements).

Comment: A piece of me died the day I learned that not all monomorphisms are injective, and I can never get that back.

Comment: Or that mono + epi is not iso in general. Which example was the first non-injective mono for you? The projection $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ in the category of divisible groups? Or an unnatural example?

Comment: Yeah it was $\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$. I don't know any truly different examples off the top of my head.

Comment: @ElliotG: Good news is that no one will be able to tell that part is missing by pre-composition :)